# How to handle navigation for a TV Application using React Native|Expo

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

im trying to make a app for TV using react native/expo. lets say im making something like netflix. A sidebar and a content area with multiple rows of items. So on pressing back/left i will need the correct item in the sidebar to be focused and also start at the first item and remember which item in a row was focused so i can navigate back to it if/when i go back to that row.

First off i noticed we have to use react-native-tvos but unfortunately the docs are pretty bad. They say it comes with a TVFocusGuideView component that "is implemented in the same way for Android TV" with a autoFocus prop that "If true, will automatically manage focus for you. It will redirect the focus to the first focusable child on the first visit. It also remembers the last focused child and redirects the focus to it on the subsequent visits.

this sounds like exactly what i need, although when attempting this and also trying the example from the github it doesnt work, it doesn't redirect the focus or remember the last focused child. It simply does what android does and navigates the rows and items like a grid. Is this autoFocus Apple TV only or something?

If it is, how would you handle TV navigation?

Thanks.

Comment: any update on how you are doing this now?

Comment: any solutions for this?